# working with PrePersist in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, registration

Well, I'm beginner in symfony and so far I developed a website where User can register himself and after login create forms dynamically, but my register form doesn't work as expected. My basic idea is when User tries to register himself, to precheck if the client number he entered already exists in the database, if it's not the case, the function throws an error, the code right below is what I thought so far but it doesn't seem to work. What exactly could be the issue?

```
//src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

    /**
    * @ORM\PrePersist
    * groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
    */
    public function onPrePersist() //orm doctrine
    {
        $data = checkFirma($_POST['clientNr']);
        if(empty($data) || $data = ""){
            throw new Exception("Client Nr is mandatory");
        }
        else{
            $this->company = $data['userid'];
            $this->rolle = $data['rolle'];
        }

    }
    public function checkFirma($clientnr){
        $connection = $em->getConnection();
        $statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT userid, clientNr, rolle FROM companyClient WHERE clientNr = :nr');
        $statement->bindValue('nr', $clientnr);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll('EAGER');
        //return $result
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach isn't very well designed cause you are violating the separation of concern principle.

Your entity shouldn't know anything about databases or statements or similar cause its not responsible for that.

Drop that validation parts from your entity and go for another solution.

I would create a unique validation rule like here

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

And handle this constraints in your controller like here

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Hope this helps